# Uploading file to pic and doc library

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm working with a webpart and saving the data to a SPList. I also got two fileUpload controls and i want to upload a picture to a picture library and a document to a document library. Is that possible? And how to? Was googling around but really don't have a clue how to. I also want them to connection with other, for example, if i save the Picture to the librar i want the picture to display it's title, and not the picture url title.
[image]

This is the code i'm using when i'm uploading the image to a picture library:

```
        byte[] imageData = null;
        if (fileUpload_Pic != null)
        {
            if ((fileUpload_Pic.PostedFile != null) && (fileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                Stream MyStream = fileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.InputStream;
                long iLength = MyStream.Length;
                imageData = new byte[(int)MyStream.Length];
                MyStream.Read(imageData, 0, (int)MyStream.Length);
                MyStream.Close();
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.FileName);                                                
               SPPictureLibrary pic = (SPPictureLibrary)SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Picture library"];//Images is the picture library name
               SPFileCollection filecol = ((SPPictureLibrary)SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Picture library"]).RootFolder.Files;//getting all the files which is in pictire library
               filecol.Add(filename, imageData);//uploading the files to picturte library

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the exact same thing with the document, but instead of using a `SPPictureLibrary` object, just call add on the `Web.Files` object and create the path to the library by using the web's url, library name, and the file name you want to appear as in the library.

Or you can do it directly to the library like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint).

After you load the file, a SPFile object is returned. You can use that to get the title property and edit the title of the picture, or anything else.

Comment: Okay thanks. But will the picture be connected with the listitem i add? Like the pic above.

Comment: By list item do you mean the document added? It could be if you made a content type (Off of Document) that had a lookup column of a picture content type and added the picture's id as that value, or simple record the pictures id as a string value on a custom content type of the document library.